# How to change color from specific csv line to the end of the line with php

Tags: php, csv

I want to change the color of the line 101 to 400(the last line) but i don't know how, here's my code:

```
    echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("Productos.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f,1000,";")) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $k => $cell) {
            $color = ($k == 4) ? 'red' : 'white';
            $class = "style='background-color: $color'";
            echo "<td $class>"  . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Best is if you assign a class to the `<tr>` tags if the line number is greater than 100. That, together with a corresponding CSS rules file will do what you want and keep styling stuff out of your logic.

Comment: Can you explain it mor in-depth please? im a total novice in php

Comment: Sure, I added an answer below demonstrating two possible approaches that make sense in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for such stuff, there is no right or wrong, everything depends on the specific situation. However there are some general agreements, for example that styling rules should be implemented separate from the markup.

I give two examples below. From your question I understand that you want to change the color from a certain table *row* on wards. However in your code you appear to work on actual table *cells*. I decided to change the row color from white to green for the demonstration purpose from a row index of 10 on. To prove that it is easy to also consider columns in such approach I additionally colored the third column yellow in those green rows. Obviously that is just a crude example.

---

Option 1: the most elegant approach in my eyes is to move the styling rules consequently into a style sheet file and *not* to rely on any specific markup details *at all*:

PHP:

```
<?php $fileHandle = fopen('productos.csv', 'r'); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="productos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
<?php while (($columns = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 1000, ';')) !== false) { ?>
        <tr>
<?php foreach ($columns as $colId => $colVal) { ?>
          <td><?=htmlspecialchars($colVal)?></td>
<?php } ?>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
tr td {
  background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(n+10) td {
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(n+10) td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Advantages: very clean and compact markup, all styling logic and rules in one single place. Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du8ha6g0/1/) I created for easy understanding...

---

Option 2: the more common approach is to enrich the markup with class names, but to keep the actual styling rules separate inside a style sheet file:

PHP:

```
<?php $fileHandle = fopen('productos.csv', 'r'); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="productos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
<?php while (($columns = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 1000, ';')) !== false) { ?>
        <tr class="<?= (++$rowId>9)? 'high' : 'low' ?>">
<?php foreach ($columns as $colId => $colVal) { ?>
          <td class="<?= (++$colId===3)? 'yellow' : 'green' ?>"><?=htmlspecialchars($colVal)?></td>
<?php } ?>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
tr td {
  background-color: white;
}
tr.high td {
  background-color: green;
}
tr.high td.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Advantages: easy to read and to understand. Here is the demonstrating [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du8ha6g0/2/)...